# encode-for-uri and absolute Windows paths

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

I've got an XML file that contains sections that start with a filename:

```
<madcapfile filename="C:\1\Outputpath\The 7% solution.xlf">
```

Each section must be saved to an individual file. 
This is my XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="madcapfile">
  <xsl:variable name="file1" select="concat('file:///',@filename)"/>
  <xsl:variable name="file2" select="encode-for-uri($file1)"/>
  <xsl:variable name="file3" select="concat('file:///',replace(@filename,'%','%25'))"/>
  <xsl:result-document method="xml" href="{$file2}">  
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
```

The variables file1, file2, file3 are my attempts so far. 
Variable file1 creates files in the correct locations for all files except those with a % in the filename.
Variable file3 creates files in the correct locations for all files, so this is a working solution.

Using variable file2 gives an error: the XSLT processor (Saxon 9.7) tries to write files to

```
C:\Path-to-XSLT\C:\1\Outputpath\The 7% solution.xlf
```

i.e. it looks like encode-for-uri treats its input as a relative path even though it starts with "C:\"
I've also tried adding "file:///" to the start of the path, that does not change the behavior of encode-for-uri.

Is there a way to force encode-for-uri to treat its input as an absolute path?

Comment: The `href` attribute should be a file URI and that means it should have forwards slashes `/` and not backslashes so try whether `concat('file:///', encode-for-uri(replace(@filename, '\\', '/')))` gives you a reliable result.

Comment: Yes, that works. So I assume the \ prevents the processor from recognizing the URI?

Comment: No, the `encode-for-uri` function will escape any backslash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two issues, the `href` attributes expects a URI and in a URI the separator character is `/` and not `\` which is used in Windows file paths. Furthermore the use of `encode-for-uri` escapes any backslash.

So to solve the problem you should replace any backward slash with a forwards slash, then you can use `encode-for-uri` to escape the percent sign:

```
concat('file:///', encode-for-uri(replace(@filename, '\\', '/')))
```

Answer (score 3):

On the specific question:

> Is there a way to force encode-for-uri to treat its input as an
>   absolute path?

The spec says of fn:encode-for-uri:

> Encodes reserved characters in a string that is intended to be used in
>   the path segment of a URI.

So the answer is no: that's not what the function is for. It's not designed to process complete URIs or to understand their syntax; it's designed to process a string that is to be used in constructing the path segment of a URI.